# How to average last ten instances of a variable and display

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi ladies and gentleman,

please forgive me if I've inputted the below code wrong as this is my first time posting here. I have a python script here that polls a capacitor every tenth of a second that is currently being used with a light dependent resistor to determine the brightness outside.

The only problem is that the numerical value often varies by around +/- 5. I would like to implement a line of code that averages the last ten polls every second and prints them. I have no idea where to start, any help would be appreciated!!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import I2C_LCD_driver
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
#define the pin that goes to the circuit
pin_to_circuit = 40
def rc_time (pin_to_circuit):
    count = 0

    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.IN)

    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_to_circuit) == GPIO.LOW):
        count += 1

    return count

#Catch when script is interrupted, cleanup correctly
try:
    # Main loop
    while True:
        print "Current date & time " + time.strftime("%c")
        print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
        a = rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("->%s" %a)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("%s" %time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list in your main loop:

```
polls = []
#Catch when script is interrupted, cleanup correctly
try:
    # Main loop
    while True:
        print "Current date & time " + time.strftime("%c")
        print rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
        a = rc_time(pin_to_circuit)
        #add current poll to list of polls
        polls.append(a)
        #remove excess history
        if len(polls) > 10:
            polls.pop(0)
        #calculate average
        avg = sum(polls)/len(polls)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("->%s" %avg)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("%s" %time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: File "lightres1.py", line 43
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks for the help, the above error is what I receive when trying to execute the script

Comment: I haven't got a pi in front of me right now so can't test directly, but it might have been indentation if you copied and pasted my code. I've edited my post to fix the indentation.